# Discretization of an EXP function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

I have a function in the form of $V = a[1-exp(t-t_0)]$ and $V_0=0$. I'm using this formula in discrete system and I need to discretize this formula and solve it every T seconds  and get the $V_{k+1}$ value based on the value of $V_k$. Is there any suggestion?
thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand your notation. What would be the initial value $V_0$?

Comment: @Math1000 I have edited the question

Comment: I believe it should be $$V(t) = a(1-\exp(-(t-t_0)). $$

Comment: @Math1000 how I can compute $V(t)$ for each step with length $T$. for example I need a formula like $V(k+1) = bV(k)+exp(cT)+d$ in which $b, c$  and $d$ are constants.